# How to print hand-written AST?

Tags: go, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a set of XML description of network protocol that I'm trying to generate Go code from, therefore I don't have any existing Go code to work with. All of the examples that make use of `go/ast` (such as `go fmt`) take existing code, do some transformation on the AST, then write them back out. Since all I have are XML files, the AST that I'm working with have to be written by hand. The problem is that I cannot get my hand-written AST to output.

[Example](https://play.golang.org/p/M3OPq_QIU4)

```
package main

import (
    "go/ast"
    "go/printer"
    "go/token"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f := ast.File{
        Name: ast.NewIdent("foo"),
        Decls: []ast.Decl{
            &ast.GenDecl{
                Tok: token.TYPE,
                Specs: []ast.Spec{
                    &ast.TypeSpec{
                        Name: ast.NewIdent("Bar"),
                        Type: ast.NewIdent("uint32"),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
    fset := token.NewFileSet()
    printer.Fprint(os.Stdout, fset, f)
}
```

Expected output:

```
package foo

type Bar uint32
```

Actual output: nothing

How do I get the AST to print?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't ignore errors!

Adding:

```
err := printer.Fprint(os.Stdout, fset, f)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Gives: "**go/printer: unsupported node type ast.File**" which should have been enough to point you in the right direction.

[`printer.Fprint`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/printer/#Fprint)'s last argument is `interface{}` so the compiler accepts anything. However, just as [`parser.ParseFile`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/#ParseFile) returns an `*ast.File` (rather than `ast.File`) it expects a pointer to a node.

Passing a pointer gives the output you want (note the `&ast.File`):

```
package main

import (
    "go/ast"
    "go/printer"
    "go/token"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f := &ast.File{
        Name: ast.NewIdent("foo"),
        Decls: []ast.Decl{
            &ast.GenDecl{
                Tok: token.TYPE,
                Specs: []ast.Spec{
                    &ast.TypeSpec{
                        Name: ast.NewIdent("Bar"),
                        Type: ast.NewIdent("uint32"),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
    fset := token.NewFileSet()
    err := printer.Fprint(os.Stdout, fset, f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/EU9mow8CGE)

Comment: +1 for the first line alone.  Great that it also answers this question, but ignoring errors is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Oops. It wasn't that I knew `printer.Fprint` returns error and I purposefully ignored it, but that I used it like it's `fmt.Printf` where normally no error check is done. Dumb question, but thanks for the answer though! Was tearing my hair out at why something as simple as printing doesn't work...